# Creating a PySide6 Modal Dialog Centered Within the Parent Window that Moves with It

Tags: qt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2, pyside6

I'm attempting to create a custom dialog that meets the following requirements:

- **The dialog should be modal, blocking input to the parent widget.**
- **The dialog should have no title bar.**
- **The dialog should be centered within the parent widget and move with it.**

In the code below, the dialog is centered and moves with the parent window. However, the main window remains interactable, which is not the desired behavior.

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets

class CustomDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent_widget):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.message = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            'This dialog is centered and moves with the window.\n'
            'But the main window can still be interacted with.')
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me')
        self.progress_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()

        self.parent_widget = parent_widget

        self.setup_ui()
    
    def setup_ui(self):               
        self.setParent(self.parent_widget)   
        self.setModal(True)

        # set background color
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #191919;")   

        # setup progress bar
        self.progress_bar.setRange(0, 0)        

        # setup layout  
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self) 
        layout.addWidget(self.message)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

        # resize
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.popup_button_clicked)        

    def popup_button_clicked(self):
        print('Popup button clicked')

        

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()       
        self.setup_ui()
    
    def setup_ui(self):
        # resize
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        # setup central widget
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # create label and button
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello, PySide6!")
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click Me!")

        # connect button
        button.clicked.connect(self.show_popup)

        # setup layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)        
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(button)  
        
    
    def show_popup(self):
        print('Window button clicked!')        
        popup = CustomDialog(self)       
        popup.show()
        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()   

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

In the second test below, I achieved the modal behavior where the dialog blocks input to the main window. However, the dialog appears outside the main window and doesn't move with it.

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets

class CustomDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent_widget):
        super().__init__(parent_widget)
        
        self.message = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            'This dialog is not centered and does not move with the window.\n'
            'The main window cannot still be interacted with.')
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me')
        self.progress_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()

        self.parent_widget = parent_widget

        self.setup_ui()
    
    def setup_ui(self):        
        # set background color
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #191919;")   

        # setup progress bar
        self.progress_bar.setRange(0, 0)        

        # setup layout  
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self) 
        layout.addWidget(self.message)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

        # resize
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.popup_button_clicked)        

    def popup_button_clicked(self):
        print('Popup button clicked')

        

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()       
        self.setup_ui()
    
    def setup_ui(self):
        # resize
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        # setup central widget
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # create label and button
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello, PySide6!")
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click Me!")

        # connect button
        button.clicked.connect(self.show_popup)

        # setup layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)        
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(button)  
        
    
    def show_popup(self):
        print('Window button clicked!')        
        popup = CustomDialog(self)       
        popup.exec()
        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()   

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

My question is: Is it possible to combine these two behaviors? I want the dialog to appear within the main window, move with it, and block input to the main window, without the greyed-out effect from setEnabled/setDisabled. If so, could you provide guidance on how to achieve this?

Thank you for your help!